# Failed first time bootup

Tags: boot, 20.04, boot-repair

I have core 2 duo system, recently installed Ubuntu 20.04, in first-time boot shows this
[image: 1]

Here is Pastebin link from boot-repair https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Ff9ppj9mvq/

Please help!
Thanks

After commenting out show this
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vu2U.jpg)

: Boot repair show this
[image]

Comment: Having the ESP in BIOS boot system, is confusing Boot-Repair. Seeing the ESP - efi system partition makes Boot-Repair think you have an UEFI install. Comment out or delete mount of ESP in fstab. But it looks like system should just boot in BIOS mode? If you hold shift key from BIOS screen until grub appears can you boot recovery mode? What video card/chip?

Comment: Its confusing I am a newbie so u have to guide me though, and I don't have any GPU/video card attached, using intel q6600 processor.

Comment: Tried to enter recovery mod got "failed to start recovery mode menu" msz

Comment: Did you comment out the mount of the ESP? You need to use live installer, mount /etc/fstab in your install & add # to start of line with `UUID=9AFD-3433` That is one of the error messages on boot. If from live installer, you drill down to /etc/fstab and double click on it, it may mount here & then from terminal you can edit it. `sudo nano /media/ubuntu/etc/fstab`. But check where mounted.

Comment: After commenting out UUID, still not booting. Now it shows last 3 failed status in above image

Comment: Persistent storage is probably referring to USB installer. That should not be involved if full install. Did you confirm that download of ISO was correct with md5sum? Or when booting installer did it run the verify correctly?

Comment: So i checked for md5sum my bootable usb dose contain md5sum.txt.  there is also 1 efi folder which contains BOOTx64.EFI, grubx64.efi, mmx64.efi . Did I have make any mistakes during making bootable usb.? I have used Rufus for that, also burn in MBR option. Now when i go for recommended boot repair it shows this (attached pic above). Hear is new pastebin link https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JxXkZVz7NB

Comment: Mount of ESP is now gone from fstab, but Boot-Repair wants you to mount a /usr partition which if separate it would not mount. But you do not have that. I might just try a new install. What brand/model system & what video card/chip?  How much RAM. If less than 4GB  a lighter weight version. Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors

Comment: Intel Core2 Quad Processor Q6600, 4gb ram, zeb g41 m-bord, no card/chip

Comment: I did not think Core2 systems had internal video. And g41 motherboard has no video out connector? https://zebronics.com/products/zeb-g41-d3-lga-775-socket  so what is connected to monitor? You obviously have video.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have an external USB hard drive attached. If so, you'll need to:

1. Disconnect the drive
2. Boot into Ubuntu
3. Edit `/etc/modprobe.d/options` to include the following line:
   `options usbcore use_both_schemes=y`
4. Reboot

After this, your machine will properly recognise the external USB disk properly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No USB devise connected. And also not getting the 3rd point